# Convert a nested for loop to a map equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, map-function

Example:

```
for x in iterable1:
    expression
```

The `map` form would be:

```
map(lambda x: expression, iterable1)
```

How do I extend this to a nested for loop using only `map` and without list comprehensions?

Example:

```
for x in itr1:
    for y in itr2:
        expr
```

Comment: Just as an aside; Try this `l = [234,124,142]; list(map(lambda x:sum(map(int,x)),map(str,l)))` :)

Comment: @BhargavRao got it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear with me on this one. Not an explanation but this worked after 2 days. Using only map and list. It's bad code. Suggestions to shorten the code are welcome. Python 3 solution

Example using list comprehension:

```
>>> a=[x+y for x in [0,1,2] for y in [100,200,300]]
>>> a
[100,200,300,101,201,301,102,202,302]
```

Example using for:

```
>>>a=[]
>>>for x in [0,1,2]:
...    for y in [100,200,300]:
...        a.append(x+y)
...
>>>a
[100,200,300,101,201,301,102,202,302]
```

Now example using only map:

```
>>>n=[]
>>>list(map(lambda x:n.extend(map(x,[100,200,300])),map(lambda x:lambda y:x+y,[0,1,2])))
>>>n
[100,200,300,101,201,301,102,202,302]
```

Much smaller python2.7 solution:

```
>>>m=[]
>>>map(lambda x:m.extend(x),map(lambda x:map(x,[100,200,300]),map(lambda x:lambda y:x+y,[0,1,2])))
>>>m
[100,200,300,101,201,301,102,202,302]
```

Another variation : I emailed to Mark Lutz and this was his solution. This doesn't use closures and is the closest to nested for loops functionality.

```
>>> X = [0, 1, 2]               
>>> Y = [100, 200, 300]
>>> n = []
>>> t = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: n.append(x + y), Y)),X))
>>> n
[100,200,300,101,201,301,102,202,302]
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to build the cartesian product of your two nested sequences, and `map` your expression to the that list of 2-tuples:

```
from itertools import product

map(lambda (x, y): expression, product(itr1, itr2))
```

Example with some actual values:

```
seq = map(lambda (x, y): '%s:%s' % (x, y), product(itr1, itr2))
for item in seq:
    print item
```

Note that the `lambda (x, y)` is necessary to unpack each 2-tuple from the sequence to the separate `x` and `y` arguments used in the expression.

Comment: This works but not what I had in mind, and you code eliminate seq by just using print inside the lambda (expression statement). I read in 'Learning Python by Mark Lutz', that, 'The map and filter equivalent of this last example would be wildly complex and deeply nested so I won't even try showing it here.'

Comment: You can't use statements inside expressions. The `print` is just for demonstration purposes. Having said that, this still addresses your question, unless you're asking about *only using `map`* - then the answer is "you can't".

Comment: Apart from the use of list I think I did it only using map. The list is for the iteration protocol. @Lukas Graf

Comment: This doesn't work if `itr2` is depended to `itr1`. Like `x+1 for x in i1 for y in x` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `lambda` is specifically limited to functions whose return value can be encapsulated as a single expression: statements aren't allowed.

One question you should ask yourself is why do you think this would be a desirable way to write a Python program? The language has been explicitly defined for readability, and you should do everything you can to maintain that readability.